# SELECT TOP query in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

Is there a way to use a SELECT TOP (n) within ArcGIS desktop?  Is appears that since the ArcGIS query builder is effectively building the SQL statement after the WHERE clause, that this may not be possible.

Here is a [typical SQL example](http://www.quackit.com/sql/tutorial/sql_top.cfm) of usage:

> SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Layer

Comment: Note that TOP and LIMIT are not supported in file geodatabases: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/68997-TOP-100

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your underlying database supports sub queries, you can build a query with a TOP N that returns ObjectIds (or any other field) and use that in your definition query.

`OBJECTID IN (*query here*)`

For example, here's a SQL Server query for a TOP 20, random selection:
[image]

The above query will return 20 *different* rows each time the map or attribute table is refreshed.  This also could come in handy for an ArcMap practical joke for less experienced users (April Fools is less than a month away).

Of course, the sub query doesn't have to be a TOP N query nor do you need to use a unique id.  Maybe work up a query to find duplicates:

`FIRE_ID IN (SELECT FIRE_ID

FROM [SandboxGeodb].[dbo].[TESTFEATURECLASS]
GROUP BY FIRE_ID
HAVING COUNT(FIRE_ID) > 1)`

Comment: nice! I can see this giving a loot of trouble to some users.."what did you do to the database???"

Comment: While I was really hoping I could do this with shapefiles, it appears I cannot.  However, this appears to be a very good way of solving the issue when calling data from a SQL data source that supports SELECT TOP queries.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use such queries within the Definition query, but is there any workaround to use them within Select by Attribute tool? It already has this SELECT FROM part pre-populated.